# Expand and shrink div based on updated ajax content

Tags: jquery

I'd like to create a div element that grows and shrinks (slides up and down) based on content returned from a user's search query.

I'm using JQuery's animate property and for the most part, it's functional. When a user performs the first query, I'd really like the animation to perform a slideDown affect while fading in the content at the same time. If an additional search query is performed, the div will grow (or shrink) based on the content returned from the server.

Right now, the first search results in an unwanted left to right slide-like effect. Subsequent queries expand the div correctly.

To illustrate this question, please see the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/krpXk/

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="search-term" />
<input type="button" id="submit-button" value="submit" />

<div id="limit">
    <div id="results"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#submit-button').click(function(e) {

     // ajax request
    $.ajax({
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        type: 'post',
        url: '/echo/html/',
        data: {
            html: '<p class="p-content">Search term: ' + $('#search-term').val() + '</p>'
        },
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#results').append(data).show(function(){
                $('#limit').animate({
                    height:$("#results").height()
                },500);
            });  
        }
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
#results {
    background:#dfdfdf;
    display:none;
    width:300px;
}

#limit { 
    position: relative; 
    overflow: hidden;
    width:100%;
}

.p-content {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:100px;
}
```

**Update:**

I found that the answer was very simple. Just by setting the #limit height to 0 forced a slide down animation.

From the answer:
"Please note, that I gave the #limit container an explicit height of 0px in the CSS in order to force the initial animation."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the content to be faded in at the same time as the container slides down, you can put some selective logic to handle the initial case that handles the opacity of the content.

Please note, that I gave the `#limit` container an explicit height of `0px` in the CSS in order to force the initial animation.

```
var wasOriginallyEmpty = $('#results').is(':empty');

$('#results').append(data);

if (wasOriginallyEmpty) {
    $('#results').contents().css('opacity', 0);
}

$('#limit').animate({
    height: $('#results').height()
}, 500);

if (wasOriginallyEmpty) {
    $('#results').contents().animate({
        'opacity': 1
    }, 1000);
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Vht6/)

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/krpXk/2/)**</kbd>

You can `animate` the `height` upto `scrollHeight`.

<kbd>JS:</kbd>

```
$('#submit-button').click(function(e) {

     // ajax request
    $.ajax({
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        type: 'post',
        url: '/echo/html/',
        data: {
            html: '<p class="p-content">Search term: ' + $('#search-term').val() + '</p>'
        },
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data) {
            var $limit = $('#limit').append(data);
            $limit.animate({'height': $limit[0].scrollHeight},500);
        }
    });
});
```

<kbd>CSS:</kbd>

```
#limit { 
    position: relative;  
    width:100%; 
    background:#dfdfdf;    
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 0;
}

.p-content {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:100px; 
}
```

<kbd>HTML:</kbd>

```
<input type="text" id="search-term" />
<input type="button" id="submit-button" value="submit" />

<div id="limit"> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `slideDown(function()` instead of `show(function()`